# analogue of `perf diff` that works across different events?

Tags: perf

I've recorded two profiles, one with `-e cycle_activity.stalls_l3_miss`, and one with `-e cycle_activity.stalls_l2_miss`. By definition, stalls on l2 are a superset of stalls on l3. I'd like to take the delta, so that I can see where my program spends time stalled on l2 but *not* on l3.

`perf diff` seems to be *almost* what I want. however `man perf diff` says "The differential profile is displayed only for events matching both specified perf.data files."

Is there a way to achieve this?

Edit: I can also record both events into one profile, but I also don't see any functionality for e.g. `perf report` to use a delta/diff between two events.